# Set date from RecordSet

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am looping through a recordset and extracting dates

```
Set dtMSDate = rs.Fields(1)
```

However, when I try to run my module, it highlights the above line and gives the error Compile error: Object required"

Is there some special thing I need to do to format/convert/cast the recordset into the date object? I am not too familiar with the syntax of VBA. I tried...

```
CDate(rs.Fields(1))
```

But that still highlights "Fields(1))" with the same error.

Thanks for helping a noob out.

Comment: Does `rs.Fields(1)` hold a value when entered in the immediate window?  Might be better to be specific about the field name - `rs.Fields("MyDateField")`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it had no affect...

Answer (score 0):

It is not an object, thus:

```
dtMSDate = rs.Fields(1).Value
```